# How to move div verticaly on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

On this page I find effect that I like and try to put it on my site but after six hour googling still nothing 
http://terranea.demos.sabrehospitality.com/
So when you clik on "guide" in navigation footer slide up.

```
#IndexGuide{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    z-index:98;
    background:#fff;
}
```

is my div CSS and with this function I get result but with no animation like on that page

```
function GuideSlide(){
    $('#IndexGuide').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': '80px',
            'z-index': '100'
        });
};
```

I look in their page source and they do something like this

```
$('#guide-toggle').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('#guide-close').toggleClass('visible');
    $('#work-cont').slideToggle();
    $('#myModal2 .close').click();
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        currentOffset = $(document).scrollTop();
        scrollPageTo(0);
    } else {
        scrollPageTo(currentOffset);
    }
    if($('#masthead,#myCarousel').length>0) {
        $('#masthead,#myCarousel').slideToggle();   
    }
    return false;
});
```

I try to modify but with no result.

Here is script that worked in all browsers for me!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var lineHeight = $('#IndexGuide').height();
    var newPosition = windowHeight + (lineHeight - 35);
    $("#IndexGuide").css({top:newPosition}, 1000, function(){});
});
var flag = 'up';
function GuideSlide(){
    if(flag == 'up'){
    $("#IndexGuide").animate({"top": "80px"}, 1000);
        flag = 'down';
    } 
    else {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var lineHeight = $('#IndexGuide').height();
    var newPosition = windowHeight + (lineHeight - 35);
    $("#IndexGuide").animate({top:newPosition}, 1000, function(){});
        flag = 'up';
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the problem? If I click on Guide, a page slides up. You mean YOU cannot reproduce in on your page? Do you load jQuery? Give us a jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/har1236/T9afD/)

```
<div class="link"><a class="open-modal" href="#myModal">Guide</a></div>
<div style="position:relative;">
<div class="header">header</div>
<div id="IndexGuide" class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

js

```
var flag = "up";
$(".open-modal").click(function(){
    if(flag == "up"){
    $("#IndexGuide").css({
        "position":"absolute", "z-index":"100"}).animate({"top": "0%"}, 2000, function() {

    });
        flag = 'down';
    } else {
        $("#IndexGuide").css({
        "position":"absolute", "z-index":"100"}).animate({"top": "100%"}, 2000, function() {

    });

        flag = 'up';
    }
})
```

reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/15626812/1699833

Comment: I use this code and slide up is working fine. but with slide down I have problem because page is responsive and how will I know how many pixel to put in top to get it back in place?  http://www.anaizadar.com/index.php is link to page!

Comment: check now the http://jsfiddle.net/har1236/T9afD/1/ again now I have used with responsive layout.

Comment: I use this but it only work in firefox, in chrome, ie and opera have some other effect. I'm tryng to figure out why.

Comment: http://www.anaizadar.com/index.php here is link. When I first time click fuction it have funy effect, after that works normaly. in firefox works just fine but in others have funny effect.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with animate(). Something like this

```
$("#IndexGuide")css({"position":"absolute", "z-index":"100"}).animate({"top": "80px"}, 1000, function() {
     // after animation stuff
});
```

You could also do it without edit the position to absolute and set a negative margin-top.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

I hope The following simple example will give you the solution as you expected. The following example is got from the link http://api.jquery.com/toggle/. I've copied the code so that you no need to search through the website.

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>  
<meta charset="utf-8">  
<title>toggle demo</title>  
<style>  
p {    background: #dad;    font-weight: bold;    font-size: 16px;  }  
</style>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<button>Toggle 'em</button><p>Hiya</p><p>Such interesting text, eh?</p> <script>
$( "button" ).click(function() 
{  
$( "p" ).toggle( "slow" );
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```